# Does LinearLayout with visibility GONE consume zero resources?

Tags: android, progress-bar, visibility, drawable, android-linearlayout

I was thinking about how to implement an *ImageView* that shows an image and while I'm refreshing its content with a new image it shows a "Loading..." text with a circular *ProgressBar* on the right, so I've written the code attached below.. Is this the correct way to implement what I want? Does the *LinearLayout* with *TextView* and *ProgressBar* consume zero resources when it's visibility is set to GONE? Does the *ProgressBar* itself consume zero resources (I'm thinking about the progress looping circle animation) when itself or it's parent layout's visibility is set to GONE? If I'd set it to INVISIBLE it should consume a bit of resources due to Layout management, but it still should not consume resources for animating the progress circle, right?

**EDIT**: when I've said "does it consumes resources" above, I meant CPU resources, since it obviously consumes a bit of memory resources since I do not release the view when I simply set its visibility to *GONE*. I've added this comment after the first comment and the first answer.

I hope the code  below is correct, in case some other newbie like me is wondering how to implement the same thing.

Follows the code and an image showing the result on an emulator:

[image]

**main.xml**

```xml
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view1"
            android:src="@drawable/fish"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="image view 1" />


       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/layout_progress"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@drawable/filled_rectangle"
           android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:visibility="gone" >

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
               android:text="Loading..."  
               android:textSize="30sp" 
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

               <!-- style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small" --> 
           <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:indeterminateOnly="true"/>

       </LinearLayout>
   </FrameLayout>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/refresh_image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:onClick="onClick" 
       android:text="@string/refresh_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**drawables/filled_rectangle.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#80000000"/>
</shape>
```

**TestFrameLayoutActivity.java**

```java
public class TestFrameLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    private int progressVisible;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);
        progressVisible = (layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)?1:0;
    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        progressVisible = 1 - progressVisible;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view1);

        if (progressVisible == 1) {
            layout.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layout.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need your view anymore, then just remove it.

Comment: @K-ballo I don't want to completely remove it, since I may need it very soon, when the user chooses to refresh the image.. if it does not consume CPU, but only memory, it is better (IMHO) to leave it in memory, ready for the next utilization, rather than destroying and recreating it when needed.. maybe it depends on the frequency of image refreshes I'm expecting to have..

Comment: Don't lose it, just remove it from the layout. When you need it again, you add it to the layout again. Nothing prevents you from keeping in memory a view that is not part of a layout.

Comment: @K-ballo Tell me if I've understood correctly: I can still define the *ProgressView* in the *main.xml* file, then I can programmatically remove it from the layout, holding a reference to it, and add it back to the layout when needed, right? But then, what is the advantage respect to setting its visibility to *GONE*? In both cases it should consume no CPU and the same amount of memory, if I'm understanding how it works..

Comment: Indeed, that's how you can do it. I would just set the visibility to GONE, but by removing the view from the layout you'd get a tiny little bit closer to _consume zero resources_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  It is GONE in terms of what is shown on the screen, but it still has a memory mapping in R.java, and it is available to the View.

If you created a View with several billion GONE children, it would likely crash as a result of memory running out.

That said, It does consume less resources because it does not need to call `onMeasure()` or `onDraw()`.

Comment: Ok, so it still consumes memory but it does not need to draw the animation and/or consume CPU resources. I don't want it to be completely freed since I'll need it next time the user wants to refres the content of the *ImageView*, in which case I'll set its visibility to VISIBLE again.

Comment: Indeed. Please make sure you mark this as correct if it answered your question. :)